# Batch file to run other batch files with parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to have a `run.bat` file:

```
C:\> run functions
```

will run \exec\functions.bat

```
C:\> run patches
```

will run \exec\patches.bat

```
C:\> run
```

will run `\exec\patches.bat` and `\exec\functions.bat` (yes, in a predefined order)

How can I do so? `Call` batch command doesn't seem to be working

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

`call` will work just fine:

```
rem if no parameter is specified run everything
if "%1"=="" goto :run_all

rem only run the batch file that was specified
call "execs\%1.bat"
goto :eof

:run_all
  call "execs\patches.bat"
  call "execs\functions.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

`a_horse_with_no_name` did the hard work - I just wrapped it a different way.

```
@echo off
rem if no parameter is specified run everything
if "%~1"=="" (
     call "\execs\patches.bat"
     call "\execs\functions.bat"
) else (
     call "\execs\%1.bat"
)
```